# Adding existing view to a code first DB Context?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a code first set of Pocos that work very well. But now I would like to add a few sql views to the DB context. Can this even be done? Or should I make a separate context and use DB First for that?

I would prefer to not use EDMX files and like the simplicity of Pocos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and the good thing is that you does not have to create additional context for this. Not even use the awful edmx.

Create ordinaries POCO classes and its corresponding DbSets, and if necessary, add mapping configuration in DbContext to those views as if they were ordinary tables. Then add your migration as usual but for those classes, delete all the migration code from Up and Down methods from the generated Configuration class and that will be all.